# Ubuntu 13.10 boots into blank purple screen after fresh install

Tags: installation, 13.04, boot, 13.10, screen

I decided that I wanted Ubuntu 13.04 on my computer. I had previously installed 12.10 LTS, and it worked right out of the box with no problems.

Later got bored of it, then formatted the entire drive blank. I let it blank for ~ 2 months. Then, I decided to install Ubuntu 13.10.

I burned it to my USB flash drive, using Universal USB Installer. The burn process was completed successfully.

Then I booted it successfully. I went into live CD mode to install Ubuntu from it. I selected install and it was pretty much straight forward by then. After the successful install with no errors whatsoever I clicked to reboot my system. I took out the flash drive, then booted. It loaded successfully to the GRUB Menu.

But when I choose to boot Ubuntu, it just goes to a blank purple screen. It stays like that forever. You may ask me to check the recovery mode and type some commands right?

- When I select to boot from ubuntu in recovery mode it also does a blank purple screen. - I try booting the memory test. Also a purple screen.
- I try to type `nomodeset` on the `gfxmode` line, still purple screen on <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>. I type `nomodeset` on the quiet splash line, still boots purple screen.
- I remove quiet splash and do the same, still purple screen.
- I tried reinstalling multiple times, the last Ubuntu version that my PC last worked on is 12.10 and 12.04. Once I install 13.04 same results as described above. 13.10 and 13.04 don't work at. They both exactly have the above mentioned symptoms.

I don't know what to do next to fix this error. I can't run recovery or pretty much anything. I request some help on my problem.

How to fix this?

My system specs are as follows :

> Inspiron 15r N5010
>  64-bit
>  4gb ram
>  Intel HD
>   Graphics
>  Intel core i5 Quad core
>  @ 2.53 ghz

Comment: Oh and btw, I am a starting to use ubuntu. So I may not understand where to put things/codes/commands/files. So please in detail explain. Thank you very much in advanced.

Answer (score 1):

I will try to answer the last question because I had a similar experience when I was trying to install Ubuntu 13.10 at my new notebook.  And I got a valuable lesson from this case.

First of all, we should understand that notebook produced over 2010 or 2011 comes with [UEFI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unified_Extensible_Firmware_Interface), that affects to installation of Ubuntu 13.04 or 13.10.

Second, make sure that you have downloaded uncorrupted installer, check the integrity size.

The differences in installation steps are:

1. When installing Ubuntu, I usually choose **Something else** partition.

   [image]
2. Then I divide partition into 4 or more parts depend on our need. The basic partitions are: `/boot`, `/`, `/swap`, and `/home` partition.
3. The most important and critical things in this installation are:

**First:**

> you should add **efi bootloader** partition

[image]

**Second:**

> after make partitions, don't forget to choose where GRUB will be
>   installed, choose from `Device for Boot Loader Installation` drop-down
>   box.  **It should be the same place where Ubuntu System was
>   installed**.

[image]

The next step is the same as previous version of Ubuntu.

Hope it helps you...